# How excute custom gradient with tf.multiply?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I define custom gradient mapper with tensorflow package.

When i use tf.multiply with custom gradient, it did not work .

whole code is here

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.RegisterGradient("MyopGrad")
def frop_grad(op, grad):
    x = op.inputs[0] 
    return 1000.0 * x 

input = tf.Variable([4.0], dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.constant(5.0)
g = tf.get_default_graph()

with g.gradient_override_map({"Multiply": "MyopGrad"}): 
  output1 = tf.multiply(input, x , name = 'multiply')
grad1 = tf.gradients(output1, input)

# output without gradient clipping in the backwards pass for comparison:
output1_ori = tf.multiply(input , x)
grad1_ori = tf.gradients(output1_ori, input)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print("with custom:", sess.run(grad1)[0])
  print("without custom:", sess.run(grad1_ori)[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TensorFlow op name for `tf.multiply` is just `Mul`, not `Multiply`. Also, `tf.multiply` has two inputs, so its gradients should have two outputs. So your code could look something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.RegisterGradient("MyopGrad")
def frop_grad(op, grad):
    x = op.inputs[0]
    y = op.inputs[1]
    return 1000.0 * x, 1000.0 * y

input = tf.Variable([4.0], dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.constant(5.0)
g = tf.get_default_graph()

with g.gradient_override_map({"Mul": "MyopGrad"}): 
  output1 = tf.multiply(input, x , name = 'multiply')
grad1 = tf.gradients(output1, input)

# output without gradient clipping in the backwards pass for comparison:
output1_ori = tf.multiply(input , x)
grad1_ori = tf.gradients(output1_ori, input)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print("with custom:", sess.run(grad1)[0])
  print("without custom:", sess.run(grad1_ori)[0])
```

Output:

```
with custom: [4000.]
without custom: [5.]
```